# Can I, a med student, buy human neuronal cell lines?

Tags: united-states, research, biosafety

Is there anything legally stopping me from purchasing cell lines of human neurons without any disclosed use (besides the ethical considerations)?

Comment: This seems to be a very niche area, so can you clarify what are "*human neuronal cell lines*" please by adding a link and relevant quotes from a reputable source.